# PhoneGap Development

Tags: android, phonegap

How easy is PhoneGap to build and deploy Android applications? The application I'm thinking of is not a beginner level app. How is the level of debugging and error handling and the support it gives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an app with Phonegap is quite easy. You can install Phonegap by using,

```
npm install -g phonegap@latest
```

and then create an app by,

```
phonegap create myApp
```

Refer the docs, [PhoneGap Getting Started](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/)

When you create the app you will notice there is a directory called "WWW". All you have to do is copy a build of your existing web app to this directory.

All your assets and code in this directory will be used to build apps for the platforms you specify.

You can use Cordova to add the Android platform, which will be used to get an Android build out of your project.

Use,

```
cordova platform add android
```

Notice the directory "platforms". Inside it you will find another directory called "android" and this will be your Android project.

To build an Android app simply use,

```
phonegap build android
```

When you run the above command Phonegap will build an Android project using your code in **WWW** directory and place it in the **platforms/android** directory.

You can then use Android Studio to open the **android** directory which is an Android project now.
It's as simple as that and quite easy once you get the hang of it.

Then you can do all the regular debugging inside Android Studio using Logcat.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I'm sorry about the delay in response.